# Apache SSL authentication connection is not permitted for expired certificate even if SSLVerifyClient is optional

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl

when I try to connect to directory on Apache via HTTPS using SSL certification authentication, where SSLVerifyClient is set to **optional**, connection is not permitted for expired certificate, but without certificate it is.

Does anybody know how to allow connection for client with expired certificate? Even if user without authentication is allowed.

I use such a directory for users without certificate to activate application and download certificate and if certificate is going to expire (is expired), it will be renewed (of course with other verification). This works on IIS and I need to migrate behavior to Apache.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> SSLVerifyClient is set to optional

This means, that a client certificate will be requested. Access is granted if the client does not provide a certificate. But access is not granted if the client provides a certificate and this certificate can not be verified. 
I agree that this behavior might sound silly, but this is how it works.